# How did Michael Garibaldi have the money to quit his job in Babylon 5 and become jobless?

Tags: babylon-5

After Babylon 5 drove away the Shadows and Vorlons, Garibaldi resigned from his job because he was unhappy with Sheridan. Unlike Star Trek, money still matters quite a bit in Babylon 5.

Like any human on Earth today, a person needs to have lots of money to show the middle finger to his boss and quit without a job. Even if Garibaldi is rich, most of his assets would probably have been frozen or confiscated by the Earth government when Babylon 5 rebelled against Earth government. He is most likely poor after the rebellion.

How does he have the means to give Sheridan the middle finger and walk away without a job?

Comment: Did you miss the part where he was living rent-free and abusing his station ID to sell his services as a private detective?

Comment: Have not reached that part.

Comment: Here be spoilers.

Comment: Yeah, this is very easily answered if you keep watching the show.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The episode [Conflicts of Interest](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Conflicts_of_Interest) answers this. In order to support himself, Garibaldi has been operating as a licensed Private Detective. He's also been using his station ID and computer access to help him solve cases.

> **Client:** *Three weeks, Garibaldi, since I asked you to help find my daughter. I haven't been able to eat or sleep since we were separated
>   during the raid on the Aris Colony. **All I get from you is silence,
>   except when you want more money or information.***

and

> **Garibaldi:** *Come on, Zack, this is me. **I'm running a private investigation company.***

Later in the same episode he helps a client get onto the station without registering with customs and acts as their bodyguard.